# Provide permission to one user to unlock items which are locked by other user in CE

Tags: sitecore-client

We're using Sitecore 8. We have a scenario to provide permission to one user to unlock items which are locked by other user in CE.

Could you please advise on it.

Comment: I used Sitecore Powershell Extensions to achieve this. Give them access to a ribbon button created by SPE and run the script using user switcher.

Comment: See: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/unlocking-items-via-sitecore-powershell-extensions-scheduled-task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote an article ["How to add a Sitecore Unlock Item Button to the Content Editor ribbon"](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unlock-item-command).

The simplest code is:

```
public class UnlockItem : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
        {
            context.Items[0].Locking.Unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to register the new command:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="contenteditor:unlockitem" type="MyAssembly.Namespace.UnlockItem, MyAssembly" />
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And add a button item in `core` database, e.g. under `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Locks` item, with `Click` field set to `contenteditor:unlockitem`.

Or just download the Sitecore content package from the [Sitecore Unlock Item Button](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unlock-item-command) article and install it on your CM server.

If you want to restrict the access to the command, break the inheritance of access rights on the new button and allow `read` access for it for the chosen role (or users) only.

Comment: Awesome. Man that is simple but worth its weight in gold to an editor.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a script I used as part of a Ribbon command in SPE.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path .
$user = Get-User -Id "sitecore\admin"
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher $user) {
    $item | Unlock-Item
}
```

Add the ribbon integration:
[image]

[image]